# How can I find iPhone apps uploading a lot of data?

Tags: iphone, data-transfer

Why do the iPhones in my home periodically use up all the upload bandwidth? Happens at least once a week, likely once a day or something.

I only notice when I get annoyed by slow internet.

How do I analyse which app is causing this this?

Comment: Some apps like Photos can use Data to upload content if that option is turned on in Cellular settings. I am not sure about a weekly behaviour.

Comment: Do you use iCloud? If so iCloud will automatically backup and upload your Photos, Videos to Apple iCloud service. Depending on your internet connection and photo data size, the upload might take some time.

Comment: In Settings > Cellular Data it will show what app is using how much data in the last period (however long it has been since you reset the usage data) which should give you an idea what the culprit might be. My wife's iPhone had her Weather Channel app using more data than Facebook and she is *always* on Facebook. So we deleted that app...

Comment: @SteveChambers this happens on wifi. Idk if it would still happen on mobile data or not but I don't want to test that out (expensive)

Comment: @nohillside how do you know it's an app that causes this? every iPhone my family owns does it

Comment: Just edit it again. But please keep in mind that asking "what is causing this" without showing any details is a reason to put the question on hold for being too broad. That's why I changed the focus slightly to ask about "how to analyze".

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear whether Bandwidth is from Cellular data or Wi-Fi setup separately. So I will do both.

In Settings → **Cellular**/ Mobile Data, after waiting for sometime, all the apps that consume data appear in descending order of used data. If Low-Power mode is off and sufficient battery power is available, then Photos and videos and iCloud Drive files will upload to iCloud if the feature *Use Data for iCloud* is turned on. To avoid extra usage this should be turned off.

For **Wi-Fi**, such usage chart is not available in iPhone natively. Two indirect approaches are:

1. See the biggest files or app-usage of iCloud. Go to Settings → Apple ID → iCloud → Manage Storage.
2. It is less accurate but go to Settings → Battery → Usage pattern. This can be a mix of a lot of activities but most apps that are at the top use a lot of bandwidth in my iPhone.